# Attached DependencyProperty with Enums act weird

Tags: wpf, xaml, enums, attached-properties

I defined an attached dependency property with type InteractionMode (which is an enum). That looks like that:

```
[Flags]
public enum InteractionMode
{
    Add,
    AppZone,
    Shortcuts,
    MagnetSelection,
    RowColumnChoosing
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty UserSpaceInteractionMode = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "UserSpaceInteractionMode", 
        typeof(InteractionMode),
        typeof(LeapConnectorProperties),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(InteractionMode.None, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None));

public static InteractionMode GetUserSpaceInteractionMode(DependencyObject element)
{
    if (element == null)
    {
         throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
    }
    return (InteractionMode)element.GetValue(UserSpaceInteractionMode);
}

public static void SetUserSpaceInteractionMode(DependencyObject element, InteractionMode value)
{
    if (element == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
    }
    element.SetValue(UserSpaceInteractionMode, value);
}
```

Furthermore i use this dependency property to mark specific UIElements in XAML:

```
<Grid ns:depProp.UserSpaceInteractionMode="Shortcuts,MagnetSelection">
```

Thus far everything is okay. Unfortunately when asking for those enums

```
InteractionMode iMode = depProp.GetUserSpaceInteractionMode(grid);
```

I get a weird result. It doesn't throw errors but the enums shown by Visual Studio when debugging are different ones, than those I defined in XAML (for example `AppZone | Shortcuts` instead of `Shortcuts | MagnetSelection`).

Even worse when checking all enum flags from InteractionMode with `iMode.hasFlag(flag)` the result is also different compared to what Visual Studio says (for example it says `true` when asking `iMode.hasFlag(InteractionMode.Add)`)

I think I'm using enums somehow wrong, but I've no idea whats the problem. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Sorry may be this question not related to your query,I'm a beginner,and i've one  doubt..Is your attached property declaration  right? can we use like that ? because field name and dependency property name are name ?Just for naming convention we append property behind that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having not specifically done what you are doing, I have seen other similar flag settings, but the enumerations needed to be binary when you are allowing more than one via OR possibilities.

```
The default is implied as 
public enum InteractionMode
{
    Add = 0,
    AppZone = 1,
    Shortcuts = 2,
    MagnetSelection = 3,
    RowColumnChoosing = 4
}

Change to
public enum InteractionMode
{
    Add = 1,
    AppZone = 2,
    Shortcuts = 4,
    MagnetSelection = 8,
    RowColumnChoosing = 16
}
```

So, if a user in the original picks Shortcuts and MagnetSelection as options, looking at binary of

```
             BINARY
Shortcut 2 = 0010
Magnet   3 = 0011
and you get 
         5 = 0101 binary, so this triggers the "Add" as "1" in the rightmost position.
```

Now, via the binary sample changed to for shortcuts and magnetSelection you would get

```
Shortcut  4 = 0100
Magnet    8 = 1000
resulting in 12
OR'd     12 = 1100
```

So now the test will properly recognize one or the other.

Comment: Its always good to know the logic running in background.. Thanks!